# MySQL return records found and display which were not

Tags: mysql

The below query will search the records and return only the records found:

```
"SELECT number, user, date FROM table1 WHERE number IN ('item1','item2')"
```

Results returned:

```
| NUMBER | USER | DATE |
------------------------
| item1  | you  | 11-2 |
------------------------
```

item1 was the only record found out of the 2 requested.

Is there a way to return all items even if they were not found in the table?

I am trying to return results like this:

```
| NUMBER | USER | DATE |
------------------------
| item1  | you  | 11-2 |
------------------------
| item2  | not found   |
------------------------
```

I am trying to mimic something like the FEDEX tracking website.  You can enter up to 30 tracking numbers and it will identify the numbers that returned no results.

Comment: I think what you're asking for is two separate queries -- one that limits the data, and one that does a `SELECT *`. Then you can chain the output inside a conditional based on if the results are in the first query or not.

Comment: I tried using a UNION and use 2 separate queries, but the second one only return blanks rows for records that are not found.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CASE LOGIC in this scenario:

```
Select distinct A.number
,CASE WHEN b.user is null then 'not found' ELSE b.user END as USER
,CASE WHEN b.date is null then 'not found' ELSE CAST(b.user as VARCHAR(10)) END as DATE
FROM 
(
Select 'item1' as number
UNION
Select 'item2' as number 
) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
FROM table1 b
ON A.number = b.number
```